# Iterating over unequal unordered pairs in one collection

Tags: c++, iterator, iteration

This code kinda hurts my feelings -- everything else in my code is done in neat one-liners, exploiting algorithms and, sometimes `boost::bind`, except for this piece. To say nothing about awkward `if(b!=a)`.

Is there a better way to do the task?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    list<int> lst(arr,arr+sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));

    for(list<int>::iterator a = lst.begin(); a != lst.end();a++)
    {
            for(list<int>::iterator b = a; b != lst.end(); b++)
                    if(b != a) cout << " ("<<*a<<","<<*b<<")";
            cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Let's start over.)

It generally looks good. You have to have two loops because you want pairs, one way or another. But if you want all off-diagonal pairs, i.e. if you mean "unequal index" rather than "unequal value", you don't need the conditional:

```
    for (list<int>::const_iterator a = lst.begin(), b, end = lst.end(); a != end; )
    {
      for (b = ++a; b != end; ++b) cout << " (" << *a << ", " << *b << ")";
      cout << "\n";
    }
```

If you mean pairs of unequal *values*, you could start like this:

```
    for (list<int>::const_iterator a = lst.begin(), b, end = lst.end(); a != end; )
    {
      for (b = ++a; b != end; ++b) if (*b != *a) cout << " (" << *a << ", " << *b << ")";
      cout << "\n";
    }
```

However, this still produces redundant output, since you don't track repeated values in the outer loop (which should be "for all *unique* `a` in the list). In that case it might be nicer to use a set of pairs container perhaps, with a suitable predicate.

Answer (score 2):

Also not really pretty, but perhaps a start

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> lst = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

    auto a = lst.cbegin();
    int first = *a;
    auto output_pairs = [&first](const int second){ cout << " ("<<first<<','<<second<<')'; };
    while(++a != lst.cend())
    {
        for_each(a, lst.cend(), output_pairs);
        cout << '\n';
        first = *a;
    }
    cout << flush;
}
```

It's C++0x because I was too lazy to write a functor for that lambda and I don't know the Boost.Lambda syntax off the top of my head.